# declaring cursor in compound trigger pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers, database-cursor

When I ran this code, I've got this error: 
 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:

```
   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character.
```

I think something wrong with declaration section but the same declaration works in a row-lvl trigger, so I'm confused is this permitted in compound triggers at all. I couldn't find the examples, so I ask you here.

```
create or replace trigger ivan_moving
  for update of country on clients
    compound trigger 
  declare
  n_country clients.country%type;
  min_date clients.bday%type;
  cursor ivans is select* from clients where fname like 'Ivan%' and Bday > (select min(Bday) from clients where fname like 'Ivan%');
  client_ivan ivans%rowtype;

  before statement is
  min_date = select Bday from clients where fname like 'Ivan%' and Bday = (select min(Bday) from clients where fname like 'Ivan%');
  end before statement;

  after each row is
  begin
   if :OLD.country <> :NEW.country and fname = 'Ivan%' and bday = min_date
    n_country := :new.country;
   end if;
  end after each row;

  after statement is
  begin
  open ivans;
   loop
    fetch ivans into client_ivan; 
    exit when ivans%notfound;
    update clients set country = n_country where id = client_ivan.id;
   end loop;
  close ivans; 
  end after statement;

end ivan_moving;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few mistakes, e.g.

- you shouldn't use `declare`
- in PL/SQL, `SELECT` requires `INTO`
- it is not `= 'Ivan%'` but `like 'Ivan%'`
- it seems you "forgot" to specify `:new` for some columns

There might be some other errors I didn't mention. I don't know if trigger does what you intended, but - at least, syntax errors are now fixed.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger ivan_moving
  2    for update of country on clients
  3    compound trigger
  4      n_country clients.country%type;
  5      min_date  clients.bday%type;
  6      cursor ivans is
  7        select * from clients
  8          where fname like 'Ivan%'
  9            and bday > min_date;
 10      client_ivan ivans%rowtype;
 11
 12    before statement is
 13      begin
 14        select bday
 15          into min_date
 16          from clients
 17          where fname like 'Ivan%'
 18            and bday = (select min(bday)
 19                        from clients
 20                        where fname like 'Ivan%');
 21      end before statement;
 22
 23    after each row is
 24      begin
 25        if     :old.country <> :new.country
 26           and :new.fname like 'Ivan%'
 27           and :new.bday = min_date
 28        then
 29           n_country := :new.country;
 30        end if;
 31      end after each row;
 32
 33    after statement is
 34      begin
 35        open ivans;
 36        loop
 37          fetch ivans into client_ivan;
 38          exit when ivans%notfound;
 39          update clients set country = n_country where id = client_ivan.id;
 40        end loop;
 41        close ivans;
 42      end after statement;
 43
 44  end ivan_moving;
 45  /

Trigger created.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll be more attentive next time.